# How to connect my search box to rotten tomatoes API search

Tags: php, html, rest, search, rotten-tomatoes

How do I get my search box connected with the Rotten Tomatoes API so I can do a search in my web page and it returns the results from Rotten Tomatoes?

I added the `$userSearch` variable in the PHP section. And I put that variable in the `urlencode` function. I am a bit lost on how to proceed. I think I need to use AJAX jQuery, do I need to create a JavaScript file that contains the code to hit the API and have an "action" inside my search box definition? I am a bit confused on how to go about this and am having trouble finding an example. I am building this off the 
[Rotten Tomatoes PHP Example](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples).

Here is my code with a "Mouse" search hard coded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="www.websitehere.com/folderhere/"
              name="searchform" id="searchform">

            <label for="Search"> Search: </label>
            <input type="text" id="search" name="myName" placeholder="Search for movie" 
                   required="required" style="width: 520px" />

            <label for="category" id="category">Category</label>
            <select>
                <option value="title" selected="selected">Movie Title</option>
                <option value="director">Director</option>
                <option value="genre">Genre</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchbtn">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" id="searchbtn">
            <p></p>
            <div id="search_results">Local Search results</div>

        </form>

        <?php
        $userSearch = 'Mouse';
        $apikey = 'myapikeyhiddenforprivacy';
        $q = urlencode($userSearch); // make sure to url encode an query parameters
// construct the query with our apikey and the query we want to make
        $endpoint = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=' . $apikey . '&q=' . $q;

// setup curl to make a call to the endpoint
        $session = curl_init($endpoint);

// indicates that we want the response back
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// exec curl and get the data back
        $data = curl_exec($session);

// remember to close the curl session once we are finished retrieveing the data
        curl_close($session);

// decode the json data to make it easier to parse the php
        $search_results = json_decode($data);
        if ($search_results === NULL)
            die('Error parsing json');

// play with the data!
        $movies = $search_results->movies;
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($movies as $movie) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $movie->links->alternate . '">' . $movie->title . " (" . $movie->year . ")</a></li>";
            echo '<img src="' . $movie->posters->detailed . ' "/><br>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for PHP in this scenario. Why make an AJAX call to your server side code to make a call to the API when you can call to the API directly from JavaScript?

Take a look at the example JavaScript code on the page you shared a link to:

http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples#JavaScript

Comment: I think the php is for when they search and submit.

Comment: You can attach JavaScript code to button clicks and a magnitude of other user actions. You can have a responsive user interface without submitting forms.

Comment: What about your javascript-less users?

Comment: I'd welcome them to the present year. Not even facebook.com works without JS. Besdies, catering for users without JS was clearly not the intention of the OP. If you read his question you will see he was considering using AJAX to call his PHP file. The clues in the J.

Comment: They should want their users to have a good experience regardless of their disabling of javascript. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement